# Need Help setting up arrays with these int variables in mind

Tags: c#, arrays

I apologize for the long call methods but I'm still very new to C# and was wondering how to set up arrays for my variables so there isn't soo much wasted coding. also the darn thing wont read the text file which have lines like this "28,m,s,3"

```
namespace project2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int livingIn = 0;
            int dist1 = 0;
            int dist2 = 0;
            int dist3 = 0;
            int dist4 = 0;
            int dist5 = 0;
            int dist6 = 0;
            int dist7 = 0;
            int dist8 = 0;
            int dist9 = 0;
            int dist10 = 0;
            int dist11 = 0;
            int dist12 = 0;
            int dist13 = 0;
            int dist14 = 0;
            int dist15 = 0;
            int dist16 = 0;
            int dist17 = 0;
            int dist18 = 0;
            int dist19 = 0;
            int dist20 = 0;
            int dist21 = 0;
            int dist22 = 0;

        int age = 0;
        int UnderEighteen = 0;
        int NineteenToThirty = 0;
        int ThirtyoneToFortyfive = 0;
        int FortysixToSixtyfour = 0;
        int SixtyfiveAndUp = 0;

        textfilereader(livingIn,age,dist1,dist2,dist3,dist4,dist5,dist6,dist7,dist8,dist9,dist10,dist11,dist12,dist13,dist14,dist15,dist16,dist17,dist18,dist19,dist20,dist21,dist22,UnderEighteen,NineteenToThirty,ThirtyoneToFortyfive,FortysixToSixtyfour,SixtyfiveAndUp);
    }

    static void textfilereader(int livingIn, int dist1, int dist2, int dist3, int dist4, int dist5, int dist6, int dist7, int dist8, int dist9, int dist10, int dist11, int dist12, int dist13, int dist14, int dist15, int dist16, int dist17, int dist18, int dist19, int dist20, int dist21, int dist22, int age, int UnderEighteen, int NineteenToThirty, int ThirtyoneToFortyfive, int FortysixToSixtyfour, int SixtyfiveAndUp)
    {
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream("project2.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader infile = new StreamReader(fstream);
        string inputrecord = "";
        string[] fields;

        inputrecord = infile.ReadLine();
        while (inputrecord != null)
        {
            fields = inputrecord.Split(',');
            if (int.TryParse(fields[0], out age))
            {
                agegroupcounter(age,UnderEighteen,NineteenToThirty,ThirtyoneToFortyfive,FortysixToSixtyfour,SixtyfiveAndUp);
            }
            if (int.TryParse(fields[3], out livingIn))
            {
                districtCounter(livingIn,dist1, dist2, dist3, dist4, dist5, dist6, dist7, dist8, dist9, dist10, dist11, dist12, dist13, dist14, dist15, dist16, dist17, dist18, dist19, dist20, dist21, dist22);
            }
            inputrecord = infile.ReadLine();
        }

        Finalcount(dist1,dist2,dist3,dist4,dist5,dist6,dist7,dist8,dist9,dist10,dist11,dist12,dist13,dist14,dist15,dist16,dist17,dist18,dist19,dist20,dist21,dist22,UnderEighteen,NineteenToThirty,ThirtyoneToFortyfive,FortysixToSixtyfour,SixtyfiveAndUp);

    }

    static void Finalcount(int dist1, int dist2, int dist3, int dist4, int dist5, int dist6, int dist7, int dist8, int dist9, int dist10, int dist11, int dist12, int dist13, int dist14, int dist15, int dist16, int dist17, int dist18, int dist19, int dist20, int dist21, int dist22, int UnderEighteen, int NineteenToThirty, int ThirtyoneToFortyfive, int FortysixToSixtyfour, int SixtyfiveAndUp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The age group tallies are");
        Console.WriteLine(" Eighteen and under = {0}", UnderEighteen);
        Console.WriteLine(" Nineteen to thirty = {0}", NineteenToThirty);
        Console.WriteLine(" Thirtyone to fortyfive = {0}", ThirtyoneToFortyfive);
        Console.WriteLine(" fortysix to sixtyfour = {0}", FortysixToSixtyfour);
        Console.WriteLine("Sixtyfive and older = {0}", SixtyfiveAndUp);
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine("The total of persons living in each district");
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 1 = {0}",dist1);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 2 = {0}", dist2);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 3 = {0}", dist3);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 4 = {0}", dist4);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 5 = {0}", dist5);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 6 = {0}", dist6);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 7 = {0}", dist7);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 8 = {0}", dist8);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 9 = {0}", dist9);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 10 = {0}", dist10);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 11 = {0}", dist11);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 12 = {0}", dist12);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 13 = {0}", dist13);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 14 = {0}", dist14);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 15 = {0}", dist15);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 16 = {0}", dist16);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 17 = {0}", dist17);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 18 = {0}", dist18);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 19 = {0}", dist19);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 20 = {0}", dist20);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 21 = {0}", dist21);
        Console.WriteLine("Distict 22 = {0}", dist22);
    }


    static void districtCounter(int livingIn,int dist1,int dist2,int dist3,int dist4,int dist5,int dist6,int dist7,int dist8,int dist9,int dist10,int dist11,int dist12,int dist13,int dist14,int dist15,int dist16,int dist17,int dist18,int dist19,int dist20,int dist21,int dist22)
    { 
        if (livingIn <= 0 && livingIn >= 23)
        {
            cancel();
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 1)
        {
            dist1 = dist1 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 2)
        {
            dist2 = dist2 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 3)
        {
            dist3 = dist3 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 4)
        {
            dist4 = dist4 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 5)
        {
            dist5 = dist5 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 6)
        {
            dist6 = dist6 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 7)
        {
            dist7 = dist7 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 8)
        {
            dist8 = dist8 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 9)
        {
            dist9 = dist9 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 10)
        {
            dist10 = dist10 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 11)
        {
            dist11 = dist11 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 12)
        {
            dist12 = dist12 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 13)
        {
            dist13 = dist13 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 14)
        {
            dist14 = dist14 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 15)
        {
            dist15 = dist15 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 16)
        {
            dist16 = dist16 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 17)
        {
            dist17 = dist17 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 18)
        {
            dist18 = dist18 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 19)
        {
            dist19= dist19 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 20)
        {
            dist20 = dist20 + 1;
        }
        else
        if (livingIn == 21)
        {
            dist21 = dist21 + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            dist22 = dist22 + 1;
        }
    }
    static void agegroupcounter(int age, int UnderEighteen, int NineteenToThirty, int ThirtyoneToFortyfive, int FortysixToSixtyfour, int SixtyfiveAndUp)
    {
        if (age < 0)
        {
            cancel();
        }
        else
            if (age <= 18)
        {
            UnderEighteen = UnderEighteen + 1;
        }
        else
            if (age >= 19 || age <= 30)
        {
            NineteenToThirty = NineteenToThirty + 1;
        }
        else
            if (age >=31 || age <= 45)
        {
            ThirtyoneToFortyfive = ThirtyoneToFortyfive + 1;
        }
        else
            if (age >=46 || age <= 64)
        {
            FortysixToSixtyfour = FortysixToSixtyfour + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            SixtyfiveAndUp = SixtyfiveAndUp + 1;
        }
    }

    static void cancel()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Data Was Entered please check your text file for any irregularities");
    }
}
```

}

the text file array was provided to me but something isn't being used properly because the counting methods don't count up and remain at zero in the final count method where I show the results of what text file has on it.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much we can do to help without doing a complete re-write of your code. There are some fundamental things about C# you haven't understood, so I would highly recommend running through a few tutorials before you start on your own project. One thing to note, though, is `agegroupcounter` isn't going to do what you want. It's modifying its own local copy of `UnderEighteen`, etc, and those changes won't be visible to the caller which is probably why it's not working at all. You *can* fix it using `ref`, but again, I'd advise going through some tutorials first

Comment: cool thank you, once again sorry for the this mess

Answer (score 3):

As Rob suggested in the comment `" there's not much we can do to help without doing a complete re-write of your code"`  But i would like to Guide you more through hints to simplify the code:

- Use an `int[]` instead for `dist1` to `dist22` and make it as global so that you can avoid passing the array and maintain their count.

  ```
  public static int[] dist = new int[22] ;  // use Enumerable.Repeat(x, 22).ToArray(); where x is an integer
  // This will give you an integer array, which are all initialized with 0
  ```
- Use a `Dictionary<int,int>` to keep the AgeGroups, with Group's max number as key and count as 0 initially.Which may looks like:

  ```
  public static Dictionary<int,int> AgeGroups = new Dictionary<int,int>();
  // initialize
  AgeGroups.Add(18, 0); // for age group under 18
  AgeGroups.Add(30, 0);// for age group under 30
  AgeGroups.Add(40, 0);
  AgeGroups.Add(50, 0);
  AgeGroups.Add(60, 0);
  ```

So that you can re-write the function `agegroupcounter` as like the following:

```
static void agegroupcounter(int age)
   {
      if (age < 0)
       {
           cancel();
       }
       else
       {
          var index= AgeGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key < age).Key ;
          AgeGroups[index] += 1; 
       }                
   }
```

The signature for `districtCounter` will be:

```
 static void districtCounter(int livingIn)
    {
        if (livingIn <= 0 && livingIn >= 23)
        {
            cancel();
        }
        else
            dist[livingIn] += 1;
    }
```

And finally the `Finalcount` will be looks like:

```
 static void Finalcount()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The age group tallies are");
        foreach (var item in AgeGroups )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" under {0} = {1}", item.Key,item.Value);
        }      

        Console.WriteLine("The total of persons living in each district");
        foreach (int d in dist)
        {  
            Console.WriteLine("Distict {0} = {1}", d,d);                
        } 
    }
```

Note : Hope that these tips will help you to simplify the code, and you will integrate them to the code. have a nice day

Comment: Just a note on `Enumerable.Repeat(0, 22).ToArray()` - it's probably better to write `new int[22]` - it's clearer and probably many times faster

Comment: Not "probably", it is more clear and easier to understand ;)
Array initalizations of the form `new type[]` also initialize every object in the array to its default (`0` for int / long, `null` for reference types, etc.). +1 for the nice rework.

Comment: @Rob:  That's correct, changes are updated in the answer; and thank you for pointing

Answer (score 0):

Have a try at this:

```
public enum AgeGroup
{
    UnderEighteen,
    NineteenToThirty,
    ThirtyoneToFortyfive,
    FortysixToSixtyfour,
    SixtyfiveAndUp,
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] dists = new int[22];
        Dictionary<AgeGroup, int> ageGroups = new Dictionary<AgeGroup, int>()
        {
            { AgeGroup.UnderEighteen, 0 },
            { AgeGroup.NineteenToThirty, 0 },
            { AgeGroup.ThirtyoneToFortyfive, 0 },
            { AgeGroup.FortysixToSixtyfour, 0 },
            { AgeGroup.SixtyfiveAndUp, 0 },
        };

        textfilereader(dists, ageGroups);
    }

    static void textfilereader(int[] dists, Dictionary<AgeGroup, int> ageGroups)
    {
        foreach (var inputrecord in File.ReadAllLines("project2.txt"))
        {
            string[] fields = inputrecord.Split(',');
            int age;
            if (int.TryParse(fields[0], out age))
            {
                agegroupcounter(age, ageGroups);
            }
            int livingIn;
            if (int.TryParse(fields[3], out livingIn))
            {
                districtCounter(livingIn, dists);
            }
        }

        Finalcount(dists, ageGroups);
    }

    static void Finalcount(int[] dists, Dictionary<AgeGroup, int> ageGroups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The age group tallies are");
        Console.WriteLine(" Eighteen and under = {0}", ageGroups[AgeGroup.UnderEighteen]);
        Console.WriteLine(" Nineteen to thirty = {0}", ageGroups[AgeGroup.NineteenToThirty]);
        Console.WriteLine(" Thirtyone to fortyfive = {0}", ageGroups[AgeGroup.ThirtyoneToFortyfive]);
        Console.WriteLine(" fortysix to sixtyfour = {0}", ageGroups[AgeGroup.FortysixToSixtyfour]);
        Console.WriteLine("Sixtyfive and older = {0}", ageGroups[AgeGroup.SixtyfiveAndUp]);
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine("The total of persons living in each district");
        for (var i = 0; i < dists.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Distict {0} = {1}", i + 1, dists[i]);
        }
    }


    static void districtCounter(int livingIn, int[] dists)
    {
        if (livingIn <= 0 && livingIn >= 23)
        {
            cancel();
        }
        else
        {
            dists[livingIn - 1]++;
        }
    }

    static void agegroupcounter(int age, Dictionary<AgeGroup, int> ageGroups)
    {
        if (age < 0)
        {
            cancel();
        }
        else if (age <= 18)
        {
            ageGroups[AgeGroup.UnderEighteen]++;
        }
        else if (age >= 19 || age <= 30)
        {
            ageGroups[AgeGroup.NineteenToThirty]++;
        }
        else if (age >= 31 || age <= 45)
        {
            ageGroups[AgeGroup.ThirtyoneToFortyfive]++;
        }
        else if (age >= 46 || age <= 64)
        {
            ageGroups[AgeGroup.FortysixToSixtyfour]++;
        }
        else
        {
            ageGroups[AgeGroup.SixtyfiveAndUp]++;
        }
    }

    static void cancel()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Data Was Entered please check your text file for any irregularities");
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it should be worth a look.